# Directus - Show collection items like this

Tags: php, vue.js, frameworks, content-management-system, directus

I'm using directus to manage content. I acessed the demo to figure out how to set up some fields and I found something very useful for my case.

[image]

On that collection "Locations" (image above), the list shows up horizontally and with the respectives images big.

I searched on the demo for what I have to do for my collection looks like that way but I can't figure out... the demo and my project settings for the respective collection are the same but the result (image below) are different.

[image]

I'm using the lastest version of directus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on the right sidebar, you'll see a dropdown for "Layout". This allows you to switch between "Table" (the bottom layout) and "Cards" (the top layout). There are also others built-in for "Calendar", etc. and you can build your own as extensions:

https://docs.directus.io/extensions/layouts.html